# Modify value of variable in Angular html file

Tags: angular, typescript, variables

I have variable of number type in typescript file. Now i want to implement post-fix on that variable in angular html file inside loop.

I have tried this: Inside typescript file

```
templateID:number=0;
```

And in html file

```
{{templateID++}} //here it gives me error
```

How can i do this? Please help.

Comment: String interpolation is for read-only expressions. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: i want to increment in that variable

Comment: Yes, I can see that. What I mean is, *why*. It would be helpful to describe *what* you're trying to achieve, rather than how you have failed to achieve it. Your approach is incorrect, and I would like to help you find a correct approach. There are a thousand ways to increment a variable - which one is right for you depends on your scenario.

Comment: ok i have nested loops. Parent loop and inside child loop. i want variable which start with 0 and end with total child length. For example if first parent has 3 children then that variable will be equal to 2 (0,1,2) at the end of child loop iteration. Now when next parent child iteration start then that variable should start from 2 not from 0. Thats what i want.

Comment: Can you post your code

Comment: <div *ngFor="let parent of parents">
    {{parent.Name}}
    <div formArrayName="children">
    <div *ngFor="let child of parent.Children; let i=index">
     <div [formGroupName]="i">   <!-- here instead of i, I need custom variable like childID becuase i start from 0 for each parent's children -->
           Child Name: <input type="text" formControlName="childName">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: This would have been more useful added to your question. Regardless of that, I've added an answer that demonstrates an approach that you could apply to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to display a number related to the current index inside `*ngFor`. You are currently attempting to increment a component-level property in every iteration of the loop.

There are 2 problems with your current approach:

1. Interpolation expressions must be read-only
2. You are attempting to use a component-level property that is different for each item of an array. Every time you increment the property, all HTML bound to that property will show the updated value.

I would approach this in a model-based way. Build a nested array of template ids that matches the structure of your existing nested array.

You haven't given any code [edit - at the time of writing], so I am going to use a nested array of strings, and build a corresponding nested array of `templateIds

**component.ts**

```js
templates: string[][];
templateIds: number[][];

ngOnInit() {
  this.templates = [
    [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],
    [ 'd' ],
    [ 'e', 'f' ],
    [ 'g', 'h', 'i' ]
  ];

  this.templateIds = [];

  let templateId = 0;
  this.templates.forEach((x, i) => {
    this.templateIds.push(x.map(x => templateId++));
  });
}
```

You can then use the index from `*ngFor` to access the `templateIds`.

```html
<div *ngFor="let row of templates; index as i">
  <span *ngFor="let col of row; index as j">
    {{col}} {{templateIds[i][j]}}
  </span>
</div>
```

If it's appropriate, you could alternatively add the templateId to your original nested array, but I think maintaining an external array keeps your code cleaner.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yc6zvh

Comment: I will try this. Thank you :)

Comment: x.map is not a function . Now i am facing this issue

Comment: Do you understand why you are getting this problem? Can you add your code to your question, and ideally create a stackblitz.

Comment: No problem :) This is not the only way of solving the problem, but as long as you understand it and it makes sense, then it's suitable.